# How to add 3D Sprite on tmx file background using Cocos-2dx?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, game-engine, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

We have been working on sample game, wherein we want to show 3D sprite on .tmx file(background). But 3D sprite is never shown up, though we tried setting `tileMap->setGlobalZOrder(-1)`.

Following is the sample code:

```
CCTMXTiledMap tileMap = new CCTMXTiledMap();
tileMap->initWithTMXFile("map.tmx");    
tileMap->setGlobalZOrder(-1);
//tileMap->setGlobalZOrder(-1000);
this->addChild(tileMap, 0);

Sprite3D player = Sprite3D::create("player.c3b");
player->setScale(10.0f);
player->setPosition3D(Vec3(200, 500, 0));

this->addChild(player, 1);
```

But 3D Sprite is never shown up. Kindly help.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set position to tile map and
Add player (sprite3d) as a child of your tileMap (background).

Try this:

```
winSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();  
tileMap->setPosition(winSize.width*0.5,winSize.height*0.5);

...    

player->setPosition(tileMap->getContentSize.width*0.5,tileMap->getContentSize.height*0.5);//----relative position of your player,you                      can acc. to requirement

tileMap->addchild(player,1);
```

this may solve your problem.